# target multiple star rating in the same page

Tags: jquery

I have several "star banners" that are dynamically generated via javascript, they form this `ul` list

```
                                <ul class="star-banner-mini">
                                    <li class="star-mini" data-num="0"></li>
                                    <li class="star-mini" data-num="1"></li>
                                    <li class="star-mini" data-num="2"></li>
                                    <li class="star-mini" data-num="3"></li>
                                    <li class="star-mini" data-num="4"></li>
                                </ul>
```

I have several of these star-banner-mini on the same page and would like to target them individually. Here is the JS code:

```
$('.star-banner-mini').each(function(){

    $(this).on('click', '.star-mini', function(){

        console.log('detect click');
        var star_li = $('.star-banner-mini').find('.star-mini');
        var iteration = $(this).data('num')+1;

        star_li.removeClass('selected');
        for(var i=0;i<iteration;i++){
            star_li.eq(i).addClass('selected'); 
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know why `"detect click"` was never printed when I clicked on each star, ie `star-mini`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lists are generated dynamically, you should use .on()'s delegated event handler syntax:

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.star-mini', function(){
    console.log('detect click');
    var iteration = $(this).data('num')+1;
    $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('selected');
    for(var i=0;i<iteration;i++){
        $(this).parent().find('li').eq(i).addClass('selected'); 
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H8T35/)**

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.star-banner-mini .star-mini', function(){

    console.log('detect click');
    var star_li = $('.star-banner-mini').find('.star-mini');
    var iteration = $(this).data('num')+1;

    star_li.removeClass('selected');
    for(var i=0;i<iteration;i++){
        star_li.eq(i).addClass('selected'); 
    }
});
```

I think the way you were trying to us on inside of an each loop was causing issues. The point of using on over just binding a click is that it does not need to be bound to each element it effects but rather the overall document. You would still need to clean up the code inside the function though, as I don't know what that was intended for.